# sklearn::TypeError: Wrong type for parameter `n_values`. Expected 'auto', int or array of ints, got <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I am passing in a hardcoded list / tuple (tried both) when initialising the `OneHotEncoder` and I get this error during `fit_transform` , not using `numpy` types anywhere (well except for the data matrix itself).

The only thing is that some of the values in that array are `None` because I am also using `categorical_features` to specify a mask (as in some of the features are real-valued and I want them to stay real-valued.

My `n_values` looks like `[1, 2, 3, None, 5]` or `(1, 2, 3, None, 5)` and

my `categorical_features` looks like `[0, 1, 2, 4]` though I have also tried:

`[True, True, True, False, True]`.

The documentation does not present any actual examples with the mask on.

**EDIT:**

So, I tried replacing `None` with zeroes and this issue went away but now I get:

`ValueError: Shape mismatch: if n_values is an array, it has to be of shape (n_features,).`

Whether I wrap my `mask` array with `np.array` or not (and when I do the shape is indeed the same as `(n_features,)`) I get this same error (though interestingly it does not complain about it being a `numpy` array anymore as long as there are no `None` values in it.

Comment: In the documentation, it states that `n_values is Number of values per feature.`  how many values each feature can take. Why the `None` ?

Comment: You should post the complete code along with some samples and full stack trace of error.

Comment: `@mkaran` Let's say your features are `[color, age, country]`. Then you want to one hot `color` and `country` values but not the age. I was trying different ways such as `[7, None, 180]` and `[7, 0, 180]` but it turns out `[7, 180]` is the correct approach. The documentation does not give any examples where non-categorical variables are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n_values` should only contain domain sizes for categorical values completely skipping out the non-categorical columns in the data matrix.

Therefore if `[True, False, True]` format is used, the size should correspond to the number of `True` values in the array or if indices are used the two arrays should be of the same size.

So there should be no `None` values but also no 0s, -1s or any other ways to encode real-valued variables in the `n_values` array.